# bootstrap align button to form submit button in td

Tags: html, symfony, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap on my Symfony app and in my index action, I display a table with all items and two buttons to update or delete an item. In fact I'm not using to buttons I use one button to modify the entity and a form with hidden inputs and the submit button to delete this item. 
Currently the submit button is displayed below the update button and what I want is to display the two buttons aligned. 
Thanks by advance if you have the solution of my problem
here is my code:

```
<td>
    <a href="/app_dev.php/quotes/2/edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Modifier</a>
    <form action="/app_dev.php/quotes/2/delete">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Supprimer</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

[image]

Comment: The left edges line up. They *are* aligned. (Presumably, you mean "aligned in some other way" but you haven't said what way that is!)

Comment: do you want to align both buttons in one line?

Comment: Raj yes I want those two buttons to be aligned in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thank you all for your answers, I find out to align those two buttons by using bootstrap flex classes, here the entiere solution:

```
<td class="d-flex flex-row">
    <a href="{{ path('wallofquotes_quote_update', {'id': quote.id}) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-1">{{ 'wallofquotes.ui.update'|trans }}</a>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ path('wallofquotes_quote_delete', {'id': quote.id}) }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">{{ 'wallofquotes.ui.delete'|trans }}</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

first thing I don't understand that why you are using a form. you can easily call the desired URL with a parameter on an onClick event.
But still if it is necessary then you can add a property to form and it's element to be `style="display:inline-block;"` or can write a separate css.

```
form {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I'm using a form for csrf_protection I don't want the user to be able to call this url with a GET method. I will try your solution thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that by many ways. One simple form would be to add `float: left` to the link, like this:

```
<td>
    <a href="/app_dev.php/quotes/2/edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="float: left">Modifier</a>
    <form action="/app_dev.php/quotes/2/delete" >
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Supprimer</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response it's a start but there's a huge space between buttons

Comment: Once there are aligned you can style the space the way you want. Like this:



`<td>
    <a href="/app_dev.php/quotes/2/edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="float:left; margin-right:5px;">Modifier</a>
    <form action="/app_dev.php/quotes/2/delete">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Supprimer</button>
    </form>
</td>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="flex">
    <a href="/app_dev.php/quotes/2/edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Modifier</a>
    <form action="/app_dev.php/quotes/2/delete">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Supprimer</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

in your css :

```
.flex {
display: flex;
}
```

good source for display with flex https://openclassrooms.com/courses/apprenez-a-creer-votre-site-web-avec-html5-et-css3/la-mise-en-page-avec-flexbox (in french)

Answer (score 0):

```
this will be helpful

<style>
.div1, .div2{
  display: inline-block;
}


</style>

 <body>


<td>

    <div class="div1"><a href="/app_dev.php/quotes/2/edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Modifier</a></div>
      <div class="div2"><form action="/app_dev.php/quotes/2/delete">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Supprimer</button>
    </form></div>
</td>
</body>
```

Comment: A div in td ? Is this valid ?

Comment: `div` inside `td` is fine!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<td class="button-container">
    <a href="/app_dev.php/quotes/2/edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Modifier</a>
    <form action="/app_dev.php/quotes/2/delete">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Supprimer</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

CSS

```
.button-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

Additionally, you can make button 100%

```
.button-container .btn {
  width: 100%;
}
```